# How to check for Raspberry Pico directive when compiling C++

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi

Given the following existing code:

```
#if defined(ARDUINO) && ARDUINO >= 100
    #include "Arduino.h"
#else
    #include <wiringPi.h>
    #include <stdint.h>
```

I'm looking to extend this to be able to detect when it is being compiled for a Raspberry Pico micro controller target.

Is there a way to do this currently?